# A basic "send an email" workflow template?

Tags: 2010, workflow

What I'm looking for is a workflow template which non-SPD, non-VisualStudio, ordinary non-tech humans can pick and use along with a list or library, which does the classic "Can we have this form send (somebody) an email when people submit this form?"

The OOB workflow templates all do nice stuff for approval and routing, but it's still too complex when what is needed is just a hair above "Alert Me". Folks, is there any such template out there? Somthing I as admin can install as a solution and make available to pelple right in the Workflow part of List Settings?

I have googled and bing'd in vain for a simple "Send an email" workflow template, and have come up empty. Fwiw, this is a SP2010 Server environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you consider buying any 3rd party product, you should maybe consider building it yourself, most simply with SharePoint 2010 Designer still, but at least consider it as reusable or site workflow.

I would estimate that you could attach to your target content types and use the "Send Email" activity, pretty simple to use while delivering the flexibility to configure the message.

I've used such approach by creating a Reusable workflow (linked to the Document content type as we want a custom alerting on document updates) which loads from a List on a top-level site the message templates.

Comment: I gave up and gave in to this very solution, producing the workflow in SPD for the persons in question. It did allow me the opportinity to embed the form contents into the resulting email, instead of just a link back to the AllItems.aspx page for the list.

Answer (score 1):

The OOB Alerts do have this capability.  Simply have the person who needs to be notified subscribe to alerts on the list where things are being submitted and they can either be notified immediately or in digest form at the end of the day or week.  This isn't a "workflow" but from what you say, it doesn't sound like you actually need a workflow.

Comment: I did consider "Alert Me", but in this case, the recipients are a mail distribution list. I should have been clearer in my question. Still, it's a good enough workaround for those times when I have one specific person wanting notification, and they are content with a notification.